# openpyxl change background color via parameters

Tags: python, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to create an xlsx file. The contents of the cells are variable depending on certain conditions and each content is associated with a background color.
To avoid having to write so many "font-colors" I thought I'd do something like this:

```
site_color = color of the condition
cellfont = Font(name='Arial', size=8, bold=False, italic=False, color = %s)%(site_color)
```

but I get two errors:

```
"(" was not closed
Expected expression
```

Comment: Please post the full output of the error.

Comment: I don't know why but now I get: `cellfont = Font(name='Arial', size=8, bold=False, italic=False, color = %s)%(site_color)
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You're trying to use string formatting on something that isn't a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Set your color parameter directly equal to your site_color.

```
cellfont = Font(name='Arial', size=8, bold=False, italic=False, color = site_color)
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment then forgot to send. It works, thank you